# Import .sql file in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have .sql file. I need to import that to oracle 11g.
.sql file contains ddl queries for all tables.
How can i import .sql file to oracle 11g.
I have sqldeveloper tool.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 28):

From SQL Developer or Toad

```
Open --> File --> /locationofyourfile/yourfile.sql.
```

Once you have the file opened in SQL Developer or Toad,

execute by <kbd>F5</kbd>

From SQLPlus

```
@/locationofyourfile/yourfile.sql
```

Comment: This is for Linux, the answer below is just for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

@ Physical path of sql file.
eg. If my file is on c: and file name is beckup.sql. Then command will be as follows(On console - sqlplus):

@ c:\backup.sql